# SharePoint 2013: Remove "Share with Everyone Option" Microblog Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I'll start this off straight, I'm an intern who got way too in over his head. I am tasked with migrating our SharePoint 2010 environment to 2013. But in doing this I need to edit some of the social features. Currently, I need to turn off the ability to "Share with Everyone" in the microblogging web part. This is what I mean:

[image]

I need to remove the "Everyone" option from both areas highlighted, but we have done so much custom development and my permissions are so restricted I can't edit the sites half of the time. If someone could give me the files that the corresponding CSS definition is in that would be great. I've been programming for years and including Web Design and UX, but I really am in over my head here, SharePoint Designer 2013 is nothing like Dreamweaver which is what they told me.

If modifying these options is not do-able through css which files do I edit? I would just search Designer 2013 for the ms.microfeed or ms.shareWith id's but my workplace has disabled searching the whole site through designer. Am I on the right track saying this is a CSS and styling issue or will I need to do something else with say JavaScript? Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated, I hope this fits into the format of a "question". If I had to boil it down to one question it would be: "How do I remove the share with everyone microblogging feature from SharePoint 2013?"

Answer (score 0):

Use developer tools (F12) to determine what css files your My Sites default.aspx page is pulling from -- the default is corev15.css, but if yours has been customized as you suggest there may be other css files taking precedence over this on your My Sites collections.

Keep in mind that if you hide `ms-shareWithLabel`, you'll take away that drop down list and restrict users from being able to share to specific site feeds that they're following. Plus hiding that menu won't change its value and it will still default to Everyone, so you won't actually be stopping anything.

"Share with Everyone" is a bit of a misnomer in these Newsfeeds. What it really should say is "Share with Everyone Following Me." If you just hide the `a` element below the newsfeed which reads Everyone (`#ms-microfeed-titleViewSelectorPivotContainer_surfaceopt1`), you've effectively hidden the org-wide Everyone feed, but folks will still be able to share with their sites and personal networks.